# NullPointerException when checking Network-State on Samsung devices

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, network-state

I have released my app in Play Store and I am using the following method for checking the network state:

```
public class TestInternetConnection {

    public boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

         ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

         if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the **Google Play Console** I see that Samsung devices crash when calling the `checkInternetConnection` method with a `Nullpointerexception`. What is the problem? On my devices and others it works just fine.

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
      at de.name.app.TestInternetConnection.checkInternetConnection (TestInternetConnection.java)
      at de.name.app.SubstitutionInfoFragment$2.run (SubstitutionInfoFragment.java)
      at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: may be context is null.
can you share error log.

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` in your manifest file

Comment: Why are you calling `getActiveNetworkInfo()` 3 times? That seems like a race condition waiting to happen. Call it 1 time and save the result to a variable, then use that variable in your `if` checks

Comment: put here your Logcat data (Exception) Hence it will be easy to find Out the issue .

Or it can be due to permissions in marshmallow devices

Comment: i added the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your function like this works fine for me in all device. Just to add the null check on context before you proceed.

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
    // Add a null check before you proceed
    if (context == null) return false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return info != null && info.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it out and check if there will still be crashes due to this method.

Answer (score 0):

Reaz Murshed's answer should fix your immediate problem, but before doing that, I think you should go through your stack trace and find out exactly where your app is passing a `null` context to `checkInternetConnection`. That's where the real source of the bug is.